# Опять mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть вот такое правило:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Ссылки вида: `/uslugi/simple-page.html` обрабатываются успешно. Но если набрать `/uslugi/123/simple-page.html`, то перенаправляет на ту же страницу.

Как избежать такого и выдавать страницу 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти правила в мод-рерайт указывают серверу перенаправлять все запросы на index.php, поместив в GET page=/uslugi/simple_page (.html отбрасывается), что предполагает, что вы обрабатываете все ссылки в index.php  и программно решаете какую страницу отдать клиенту (так называемый роутинг или Front Controller).
Это значит, что для того, чтобы перенаправить пользователя на 404 страницу при запросе /uslugi/123/simple-page.html, желательно править обработку УРЛ в скрипте, а не в рерайте ИМХО

Comment: Подход правильный, но есть маленький нюанс - не хочу лезть в код CSM madesiple... как-то оно..